# Talend job not loading all rows retrieved from tSalesforceInput to Snowflake DB

Tags: salesforce, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

[image]

I have a simple job (as in image) that connects to Salesforce, gets the data, and loads it into Snowflake. The tFlowMeter logs the number of rows returned. I see that it logs that all the rows (about 500K) were obtained from the tSalesforceInput component. However, when I query the Snowflake DB, I have about 80k rows missing. The Talend run completes successfully. I have manually checked some IDs which are missing from Snowflake and don't see any data in the rows that could stop them from loading into the DB.

When I look at the Snowflake "history" tab, I see that the property "on_error" is set to "continue" (as in the screenshot below). How do I change this property in the tDBOutput component (that I use to load the Snowflake DB) to fail and log/throw the error?

[image]

PS: I started working on Talend less than two months ago. Please excuse any silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should find an option called **Die on error** to activate in your component **tDBOutput** (**Basic settings** tab).

This will use `on_error='ABORT_STATEMENT'` instead of **CONTINUE** and will throw an error in case of problems during the data uploading phase.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your input. I did read about that property and try to find it on the component. I am on Talend 7.3 and the tDBOutput component does not have the property of "die on error" in the basic or advanced settings. @CMe

Comment: @NBaliga This screenshot was made on Talend ESB 7.3.1. Which talend version you are working on ? Aditionnaly could you precise if it's studio (free) or entreprise version.